# Proof of a convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $X$ is a separable reflexive Banach space and:

$A:X\to X^*$ is a NONlinear operator.

$x_n\to x$ strongly (with norm) in $X$.

$A(x_n)\to f$ weakly in $X^*$.

I want to prove:

$(A(x_n))(x_n)\to f(x)$

I just proved it in case that $A$ is linear. This is my effort:

$|(A(x_n))(x_n)-f(x)|=\\|(A(x_n))(x_n)-f(x)+(A(x_n))(x)-(A(x_n))(x)|=\\|(A(x_n))(x_n)-(A(x_n))(x)+(A(x_n)-f)(x)|\le \\|(A(x_n)(x_n)-(A(x_n))(x)|+|(A(x_n)-f)(x)|$

The second term tends to zero according to definition of weak topology on $X^*$, but how about first term? if $A$ was linear, because of weak-boundedness of $A(x_n)$ and so operator-norm-boundedness of $A(x_n)$ in $X^*$ the first term also tended to zero. I repeated such argument with addition/elimination of $f(x_n)$ and encountered with similar problem.

Comment: Why do you mean a by non-linear operator ? Is A just a general map of sets ? If so, I don't see how you could prove this. You probably want A to be continuous, I guess...

Comment: Yes.With no further restrictions on A,  there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I don't see any problem: the sequence $(A(x_n))$ is weakly bounded in $X^*$, so it is norm bounded. Linearity of $A$ plays no role here.

Comment: @Etienne: I know linearity has no role for being norm bounded, I said if A is linear I use these two fact and prove first term also tends to zero.

Comment: @Etienne: You are right, user "grew" in his answer opened my eye. My proof is correct because $A(x_n)$ are linear, linearity of $A$ is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Try to prove:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space. The sequence $\{x_n\} \subset X$ converges strongly to $x \in X$, i.e., $x_n \to x$, and the sequence $\{x_n^*\} \subset X^*$ converges weak-* to $x^*$, i.e., $x_n^* \stackrel{*}{\rightharpoonup} x^*$. Then
>   $$ x_n^*(x_n) \to x^*(x).$$

To do so, first show the boundedness of $\{x_n^*\}$.

Note that reflexivity or separability of $X$ is not needed, but the completeness is crucial.

Finally, you set $x_n^* = A(x_n)$ and $x^* = f$.

Comment: You are right, If you read my answer I didn't noticed that $A(x_n)$ are linear. My proof is correct because $A(x_n)$ are linear, linearity of $A$ is not important. I write answer with elimination of A. But I can't see role of completeness?

Comment: Completeness is necesary I got it.

Comment: Just for the record: Completeness of $X$ is necessary for the implication "$\{x_n^*\}$ weak-* convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\{x_n^*\}$ is norm bounded".

Comment: YES. If we have reflexive normed space can we use Theorem 3.18 of Functional Analysis, Rudin?

Comment: Yes, but you have to be a little bit careful. As a locally convex space in Thm. 3.18, you take $X^*$ with its norm topology. Since $X$ is reflexive, the dual of $X^*$ is $X$ and the weak topology coincides with the weak-* topology.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and:

$x_n\stackrel{{\|\|}_X}\longrightarrow x$ in $X$.

$f_n\stackrel{{weak}^*}\longrightarrow f$ in $X^*$.

Then:

$f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$

Proof:

$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|=\\|f_n(x_n)-f(x)+f_n(x)-f_n(x)|=\\|f_n(x_n-x)+(f_n-f)(x)|\le \\ {\|f_n\|}_*{\|x_n-x\|}_X+|(f_n-f)(x)|$

The second term tends to zero according to definition of weak* topology on $X^*$ and about first term we know for dual of a Banach space weak*-boundedness implies operator-norm-boundedness and so first term tends to zero too.